# Sequence Proof with Binomial Coefficient

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose  $\lim_{n\to \infty }z_n=z$.

Let  $w_n=\sum_{k=0}^n {2^{-n}{n \choose k}z_k}$

Prove $\lim_{n\to \infty }w_n=z$.

I'm pretty sure I need to use $\sum_{k=0}^\infty{n \choose k}$ = $2^{n}$ in the proof. Help? Thoughts?

Comment: I guess the first summation is over $k$, not $n$.

Comment: Right. Thanks. Should be k=0 to n rather.

Comment: A detail: You want to use that $$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}={2^n}$$, careful with the $\infty$ atop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$w_n-z=\sum_{k=0}^n2^{-n}\binom{n}k(z_k-z)$$

Fix $\epsilon>0$. There is an $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $|z_k-z|<\frac{\epsilon}2$ whenever $k\ge m$. Clearly

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^m2^{-n}\binom{n}k=0\;,$$

so there is an $r\ge m$ such that $$\sum_{k=0}^m2^{-n}\binom{n}k|z_k-z|<\frac{\epsilon}2$$ whenever $n\ge r$.

Then

$$\begin{align*}
|w_n-z|&\le\sum_{k=0}^m2^{-n}\binom{n}k|z_k-z|+\sum_{k=m+1}^n2^{-n}\binom{n}k|z_k-z|\\
&\le\sum_{k=0}^m2^{-n}\binom{n}k|z_k-z|+\sum_{k=0}^n2^{-n}\binom{n}k|z_k-z|\\
&\le\frac{\epsilon}2+\frac{\epsilon}2\sum_{k=0}^n2^{-n}\binom{n}k\\
&=\epsilon
\end{align*}$$

for $n\ge r$.

Comment: Could you walk me through the thought process for this proof? I feel like some of the steps are just so far over my head that I'm not sure it's something I could do on my own. Why are we fixing $epsilon > 0$? Why was $z$ subtracted? How did we know to use $m$? I'm just starting to write proofs and the creative process is something I'm struggling with.

Comment: @user63782: You want to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}w_n=z$; this is the same as proving that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(w_n-z)=0$, which is what I’ve done in my answer. To prove this, you must show that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $r\in\Bbb N$ such that $|w_n-z|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge r$; that’s just the definition of convergence. Because $z_n\to z$, I know that if I make $n$ large enough, I can ensure that $|z_n-z|$ is as small as I please; in this case I wanted it to be less than $\epsilon/2$ and chose $m$ so that $n\ge m$ would make it so.

Comment: That ensures that $\sum_{k=m+1}^n2^{-n}\binom{n}k|z_k-z|<\epsilon/2$ when $n>m$. Then I have to make the sum from $k=0$ to $m$ small, which I do by making $m$ a small fraction of $n$, so that the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}k$ with $k\le m$ are a small part of the total of $2^n$.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, thanks. Just out of curiosity, could this be proven another way without setting the original limit = 0?

Comment: @user63782: Sure: $w_n\to z$ and $w_n-z\to 0$ are pretty much interchangeable, and you end up doing the same things to prove them. I just didn’t see the argument until I thought of subtracting $z$ to get change the target limit to $0$; for some reason that made the right approach more obvious to me.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not what you are looking for, but here is a solution using probability.

Let $(X_j)$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli (1/2) random variables, 
and let $S(n)=X_1+\cdots+X_n$. The law of large numbers guarantees that $S(n)\to \infty$ almost surely, so by bounded 
convergence we have 
$$w_n=\mathbb{E}(z_{S(n)})\to \mathbb{E}(z_{\infty})=z.$$

---

**Hint:** Since $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-n}{n \choose k}=1$, the result is true for constant sequences. So you may subtract off $z$, i.e., suppose without loss of generality that $z=0$. When $z_n\to 0$, it  isn't too hard to bound $|w_n|$.